# Apache (2.0) mod_headers not outputting environment variables?

Tags: apache, http-headers

My .htaccess file:

```
Header add X-Hello "time %D"
```

Now I check to see what it looks like, check out the `X-Hello` header:

```
$curl -v http://foo.com/bar.php
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2010 20:43:39 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7d32d8fch8qrnnuvoqqopr74c0; path=/
< X-Hello: time %D
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
```

Which is clearly contrary to the Apache documentation below.  Is there some other directive that `mod_headers` needs in order to interpolate environment variables?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#examples

Comment: If it should be moved I think it should be on serverfault rather than superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without note otherwise, hosting provider admitted to still using Apache 1.3 which does not interpolate values in `mod_header`.